# Process.Start to open an URL, getting an Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to open an URL following a simple method written all over google and even MSDN. But for unknown reasons I get an Exception as follows:

```
Win32Exception was unhandled

Message: Application not found
```

[image: Exception]

Here's my code:

```
private void linkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://github.com/tbergeron/todoTxt");
    Process.Start(sInfo);
}
```

Any idea why it is failing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://devtoolshed.com/content/launch-url-default-browser-using-c  ff as default browser may cause such error

Comment: I had this idea but I don't want to force any user to use any browser.

Comment: Could you provide the error code of the Win32Exception? You will find a property called ErrorCode and NativeErrorCode on the Win32Exception class.

Comment: did you manage to fix this cleanly?

Answer (score 86):

I had a similar issue trying this with .NET Core and getting a `Win32Exception`, I dealt with it like so:

```
var ps = new ProcessStartInfo("http://myurl")
{ 
    UseShellExecute = true, 
    Verb = "open" 
};
Process.Start(ps);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, nothing else worked in .NET Core 3.

Comment: [`UseShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8#property-value) by default it set to `true` in .NET Framework and to `false` in .NET Core, I guess it's a reason of exception

Comment: For me, Verb= "Open" is not required, it works without.

Comment: Works well on .Net6.0

Answer (score 10):

This is apparently machine-specific behaviour (http://devtoolshed.com/content/launch-url-default-browser-using-c).

The linked article suggests using `Process.Start("http://myurl")` but catching `Win32Exception` and 
falling back to `Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://myurl")`:

```
try
{
  Process.Start("http://myurl");
}
catch (Win32Exception)
{
  Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://myurl");
}
```

Sadly after trying almost everything, this was the best I could do on my machine.

Comment: You should use `catch( Win32Exception w32Ex ) when ( w32Ex.NativeErrorCode == 0x800401F5 /* CO_E_APPNOTFOUND */ )`. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751559/159145

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `string` overload of `Process.Start()`:

```
Process.Start("http://github.com/tbergeron/todoTxt");
```

Comment: Are you sure? I could repro your exception but calling with the string version worked well. Your machine is probably misconfigured.

Answer (score -1):

Throw start in front of it, if you want to launch in the default browser:

```
new ProcessStartInfo("start http://github.com/tbergeron/todoTxt");
```

Comment: This is supposed to launch the default browser. I don't want to force ANYONE to use iexplore LOL.

Comment: @Tom. Good point. I actually don't know off the top of my head how to launch the default browser.