# How to use Process.Start() with unicode-Symbols (such as )

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I am trying to start an URL with an Unicode symbol using `Process.Start()` but it gives mit a Win32Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

(English: "The system can not find the file specified")

The URL I am trying to call is http://.la (this is a valid url, at least for Firefox 38)

After @Codo 's Suggestion I altered my code to this:

```
string link = "http://.la";
try
{
    Process.Start(link);
}
catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
{
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", link);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried URL escape format? %F0%9F%92%A9 (http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%92%A9)

Comment: You could have chosen less "offending" characters for your example ;-) but anyway. You could always use [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) and feed that into APIs you call.

Comment: Process.Start("http://.la"); works just fine.  You are doing it wrong, we can't see you doing it wrong.  Use capital U to encode unicode codepoints in the upper bit plans.

Comment: @GuyMontag, Both of the following work fine for me on Windows 8.1 and IE 11 (11.0.9600): `Process.Start("http://xn--ls8h.la/");` or `Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://xn--ls8h.la/");`. What is your version of Windows and IE?

Comment: That's Windows 7 Enterprise (64Bit, SP1) and IE 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't let Firefox fool you. Unicode characters beyond the ASCII codes and in particular emojis aren't allowed in a URL; they need to be encoded. Firefox is user-friendly, accepts them, displays them but automatically encodes them once it executes the request.

If the Unicode character is in the domain name, it needs to be [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encoded. If the Unicode character is after the domain name, it needs to be URL encoded.

The effective URL for your case is: http://xn--ls8h.la/

Comment: Hi, thank you so far, thats good to know. Unfortunately `Process.Start("http://xn--ls8h.la/")` produces the same error (maybe tries to convert punycode and ends up with the same url as before...?)

Comment: Can you open any URL at all with your code? Is it really related to emojis?

Comment: It is related to the emoji, that is for sure. I can provide a code sample but any url works fine (even emoticons in path such as: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/). But emoticons in the domain name produce the exception

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? And what is your default browser? Other people have similar issues, though not specifically related to emojis. Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509782/413337 ?

Comment: This is Windows 7 Enterprise and the default browser is Firefox. I will try the solution you linked tomorrow. Thanks in advance

Comment: All right, when I try `Process.Start("IExplore.exe", link)` (with either punycode-link or emoji), Internet Explorer is started but the default site is displayed. Other Hyperlinks with emojis in the path work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

http://xn--ls8h.la/ (Punycode)

http://%F0%9F%92%A9.la/ (URL Escape Code)

Take a look at [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). URLs can only consist of US-ASCII characters.