# What is the best way to handle a specific Win32 Exception like "application not found"?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, win32exception

I start a process with the default application for the file type, but if the user has deleted his default application, a Win32Exception is thrown. In addition there are other cases when a Win32Exception is thrown e.g. if the user has no rights to open the default application.

Now I'm looking for the best way to seperate between the exceptions.

How can i check which exception exactly is thrown? Is the only way to check it by its Exception message?

I'm catching it like this:

```
        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception exc)
        {
//How to check which exception exactly is thrown?
            return return string.Format("Process cannot be started", exc.Message)
        }
```

This was mit first idea but i think there is a better way to accomplish this task:

```
catch (Win32Exception exc)
        {
            if(exc.Message == "Application not found")
            { 
              //Do something
            }
            else if(exc.Message == "Another exception")
            { 
              //Do something else
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using the message is a bad idea because it will change depending on the locale of the user. Instead, you should use the `NativeErrorCode` property of the exception

Answer (score 2):

With `Win32Exception` you may need to check **both** `Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode` and its inherited `ExternalException.ErrorCode` values.

C# 6 introduces exception filters which allow you to opt-in to handling an exception without needing to rewind the stack prematurely if you intend to re-throw the exception.

There are three main types of error-codes in Windows: HRESULT, Win32 Error Codes, and COM error codes.

- `HRESULT`:

  - `HRESULT` values are actually self-describing bit-fields and the format is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a
  - They're exposed as `Exception.HResult`.
  - Note that `Exception.HResult` has a default value of `-2146233088` (`0x80131500`)
- Win32 error codes:

  - These are listed on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d?redirectedfrom=MSDN
  - They're exposed only on `Win32Exception` in the `Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode` property.
- COM error codes are listed on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-error-codes-1

  - These are chiefly exposed via `COMException` in the `COMException.HResult` property.
  - However some places in .NET will throw a `Win32Exception` instead of a `COMException`, and the `Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode` will contain the COM error code instead of a Win32 error code.

    - `Process.Start()` is one such example. This is explained below.
  - `COMException` is also used for SEH (Structured Exception Handling), but normally you won't encounter that in .NET.

---

On to your question: The "Application not found" error message is from COM: `CO_E_APPNOTFOUND` and is `0x800401F5` - but curiously it's returned in a `Win32Exception` rather than a `COMException`.

What's interesting is that the .NET Framework (I haven't checked .NET Core), [`Process.Start` always throws `Win32Exception` for both the `UseShellExecute == true` and `false` branches](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/40054df689616fb5.html). But when `UseShellExecute == true` then COM is used, so the COM error is simply passed-into `Win32Exception`s constructor and it just magically works (because `Win32Exception` calls `FormatMessage` to get the human-readable error message from the error-code, and `FormatMessage` supports returning error-messages for Win32, HRESULT and COM status codes (as they generally don't overlap).

...which means we just need to do this:

```
const Int32 CO_E_APPNOTFOUND = unchecked( (Int32) 0x800401F5 );

try
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo( "https://www.stackoverflow.com" );
    psi.UseShellExecute = true;
    psi.Verb = "open";

    using( Process p = Process.Start( psi ) )
    {
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch( Win32Exception w32Ex ) when ( w32Ex.NativeErrorCode == CO_E_APPNOTFOUND )
{
    MessageBox.Show( "You don't have a web-browser installed or configured correctly." );
}
```

Comment: C# 6 introduced the exception filters, not 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

`Win32Exception` has a property called `ErrorCode`, that returns the error `HRESULT`. With this, you can properly classify your exception, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx) link here.

Comment: Check `Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode` as well, as certain errors like COM errors all have the same `ErrorCode` but have different `NativeErrorCode` values (especially when `ErrorCode == -2147467259`).