# C# Windows Form Only working successfully on my computer, I tried To change framework versions

Tags: c#

Ok, so I spent a good portion of the past couple of days working on an application. its basically a hub for stuff I release. Anyways when I try to run it on my computer I get no errors, but when anyone else tries to run it they get an error that I can shorten to "Unhandled Exception, Application Not Found" but from what I could tell this was happening only when they clicked on two different button's that was supposed to send them to a website. Here is the code for the button's.

I tried doing some research to no avail, any ideas?

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://examplewebsite.com");
```

Comment: Therefore it is extremely useful to add Logging to your application.

Comment: Use `ProcesStartInfo` first instead of using only `Process.Start`, and ensure `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` and `ProcessStartInfo.Verb = "open"`.

Comment: I have just attempted to try that and I get the same exception on the other computer? Im just sitting here with a brain fart. any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core? If so, what version? And please edit your question so it contains your updated code that uses `ProcessStartInfo`, and please post the full exception details, including the full `StackTrace` and all `InnerException` entries.

Comment: Does the `Win32Exception` that's thrown have a `NativeErrorCode == 0x800401F5`? If so, then that means your other computer does not have a web-browser correctly configured. See my answer to this other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751559/159145