# Process.Start() open URL throws Win32Exception sometimes?

Tags: c#, windows, browser, process, system.diagnostics

I have the following code to open a URL in default browser:

```
string url;
//...
Process.Start(url);
```

But it will fail and throws a `Win32Exception` with some URL, for example:

`https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E6%95%B8%E4%BD%8D%E8%BA%AB%E5%88%86%E8%AD%89%E6%93%AC9%E6%9C%88%E6%8F%90%E6%A8%A3%E5%BC%B5-%E5%BE%90%`

The stack trace is like:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at MyApp.GoURL(String url)
```

I have been switching deafult browsers from firefox to chrome, edge, brave, ... etc.

And I tried some workarounds in [this dotnet issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10361),

```
Process.Start(
    new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") 
    { CreateNoWindow = true });
```

or

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = url,
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

but still no luck, cannot open my default browser. The error message is still `The system cannot find the file specified.`

There are some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693429/process-start-to-open-an-url-getting-an-exception) opening internet explorer, but they do not fit my spec.

How could I open such url in any default browser?

Comment: The error message says it couldn't locate the file.This very likely due to the incorrect path given.

Comment: @Daredevil I think it should open my default browser, and show a 404 page if the URL is incorrect?

Comment: It could be but could you post the entire stack trace error?

Comment: @Daredevil I added the stack trace to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the [UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder) class do the *decoding* work for you.

```
string urlEncoded = @"https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E6%95%B8%E4%BD%8D%E8%BA%AB%E5%88%86%E8%AD%89%E6%93%AC9%E6%9C%88%E6%8F%90%E6%A8%A3%E5%BC%B5-%E5%BE%90%";

var builder = new UriBuilder(urlEncoded);
Process.Start(builder.ToString());
```

It's actually just a small modification to the original string, adding the service port, but it's enough for the string to become a recognized URL.

It won't work if you try to decode it, using the [WebUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility) class:

```
 string urlDecoded = WebUtility.UrlDecode(urlEncoded);
 Process.Start(urlDecoded);  // Fail
```