# How is it possible to open a .url application shortcut in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to run an app using a `.url` link using `Process.Start()` but, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-8.0):

> If the address of the executable file to start is a URL, the process is not started and `null` is returned.

Is there a workaround? There is absolutly no way to launch this app in another way.

Here was my code and its error message:

```cs
Process proc = new Process();
Trace.WriteLine(MainDataModel.Default.FilePaths.ExecutableDirectory + "\\Minecraft Preview_Editor.url");
proc.StartInfo.FileName = MainDataModel.Default.FilePaths.ExecutableDirectory + "\\Minecraft Preview_Editor.url";
proc.Start();
```

```
BedrockLauncher.Exceptions.AppLaunchFailedException: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\\Users\<me\>\\Documents\\GitHub\\BedrockLauncher\\BedrockLauncher\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0\\Minecraft Preview_Editor.url' with working directory 'C:\\Users\<me\>\\Documents\\GitHub\\BedrockLauncher\\BedrockLauncher\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693429/process-start-to-open-an-url-getting-an-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Antony Kao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10293903/antony-kao) for commenting [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245993/21437709)

```cs
var ps = new ProcessStartInfo("http://myurl")
{ 
    UseShellExecute = true, 
    Verb = "open" 
};
Process.Start(ps);
```

Comment: The trick is to set `UseShellExecute` to true since when it is false then the URL file will be treated as an executable file.

Comment: Note that according to the `UseShellExecute` property docs, *The default is true on .NET Framework apps and false on .NET Core apps.*

Comment: I believe the `Verb = "open"` line is redundant.